# SVN Error : "svnadmin: E205000: Too many arguments"

Tags: c#, svn, process, svndump

I am trying to back up my reposotries using a C# Code

```
        Process svnCommand = null;
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("svnadmin");
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.Arguments= @"dump C:\Repositories\Myrepo > C:\temp\myrepodumpfile.dump";

        using (svnCommand = Process.Start(psi))
        {     
            var myoutput = svnCommand.StandardOutput;

            var myerror = svnCommand.StandardError;



            Debug.Write("Output :" + Environment.NewLine +
                Environment.NewLine + myoutput.ReadToEnd() +
                Environment.NewLine + "Error :" +
                Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                myerror.ReadToEnd());

            svnCommand.Close();
        }
```

When i use the dump command from the commandline

`svnadmin dump C:\Repositories\Myrepo > C:\temp\myrepodumpfile.dump`

it works fine but when i try to use it through C# code given above it gives error as

`svnadmin: E205000: Try 'svnadmin help' for more info`
`svnadmin: E205000: Too many arguments`

My SVN info :

SVN version 1.7.5
Environment variable aslo set (i can use sv directly from cmd)

Cant seem to figure out whats the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` is a feature of the command line; you can't use it when launching a process from C#.

What `>` does is it takes the output that the process writes to StandardOutput and writes it to a file. That's what you need to also implement in your program, e.g.

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("svnadmin");
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.Arguments= @"dump C:\Repositories\Myrepo";

using (var svnCommand = Process.Start(psi))
{     
    var myoutput = svnCommand.StandardOutput;

    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\myrepodumpfile.dump", myoutput.ReadToEnd());

    svnCommand.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ... but i have one query... `svnadmin dump` reports success and failure in the `StandardError` stream. how will i know that the dumped is successful or not.

Comment: You can check `process.ExitCode` (it will be 1 for all errors and 0 for success)